# Callback on completion of AsyncApexJob

Tags: asynchronous, asyncapexjob, callback

Is there a way to have Apex code execute when an asynchronous job finishes? I want to solve this problem without polling (which seems to be the dominant solution).

Comment: Could you be more specific? What type of code do you want to run after the job finishes?

Comment: Did you add the `Cron` tag because you're using [Scheduled Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm)?

Comment: I want to run Apex code on completion of the job. Yeah the cron tag is unnecessary. I'll remove it.